# PLay framework Routing with multiple parameters issue

Tags: java, groovy, routes, playframework

I don't seem to be able to resolve the following scenario where no routes are found.

Got my route file with the following entry:

```
GET     /reports/items/{date}                          Reports.items(field:'all')
```

and the controller defined with

```
public static void items(@Required Date date, String field){
...
}
```

the view is using @{items(date)} or @{items(date,'all')}

the url translates to:
localhost:9000/reports/items/19-07-2011?field=all

I always seem to get not found with:

```
tried the following route
GET       /                                                 Reports.index
GET       /reports/items/{date}                             Reports.items
```

Any idea on how I can route and default field to 'all' if it is not provided?

Comment: Why your controller method isn't named : items ? How the route can find atmItems?

Comment: Actually is. this was a copy and paste mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is this:

```
GET       /reports/items/{date}                     Reports.items(field:'all') 
GET       /reports/items/{date}/{field}             Reports.items
```

First the system will match the request with only date (which will use 'all' as default value for field).

If it doesn't match, because you added the field, it will go to the second GET where both parameters will be mapped to the controller.

Comment: I still don't understand why the @{items(date)}  does not match with the first routing line and field defaulted to 'all'

Comment: Because your controller has 2 fields. It's @{items(date, field)}. The automatic value assigned in Routes is just syntax sugar to facilitate redirects.